# How to calculate positions of new points after image rotation

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a positions of new points `P1_r(x1_new, y1_new)` and `P2_r(x2_new, y2_new)` after image rotation using `imutils.rotate_bound()`. Original image contain line defined by points `P1(x1, y2)` and `P2(x2, y2)`.

```
import imutils
import numpy as np

P1 = np.array([x1, y1])
P2 = np.array([x2, y2])
```

The starting position is as follows (*green area represents an image*):

[image]

Before rotation I have to calculated the `angle` between line defined by points `P1(x1, y2)`, `P2(x2, y2)` and by `y-axis` (*in this case is y-axis represented by green line*):

[image]

Then is necessary to calculate the `angle` where is used function `np.arccos()`:

```
if (P2[1] - P1[1]) < 0:
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, -1])
else:
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, 1])

if (P2[0] - P1[0]) < 0 and (P2[1] - P1[1]) :
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, 1])

p_unit_vector = (P2 - P1) / np.linalg.norm(P2-P1)
angle = np.arccos(np.dot(p_unit_vector, y_axis_vector)) * 180 / math.pi
```

Then is possible to rotate the image:

```
rotated_image = imutils.rotate_bound(original_image, -angle)
```

So result should looks like:

[image]

Now I am trying to calculate positions of new points `P1_r(x1_new, y1_new)` and `P2_r(x2_new, y2_new)`. I tried to use "standard" `sin()` and `cos()` functions to calculate new `x` and `y` positions for point `P1_r`:

```
x1_new = y1 * sin(angle) + x1 * cos(angle) 
y1_new = y1 * cos(angle) - x1 * sin(angle)
```

and for point `P2_r`:

```
x2_new = y2 * sin(angle) + x2 * cos(angle)
y2_new = y2 * cos(angle) - x2 * sin(angle)
```

However it `doesn't work`, because the whole picture is rotated, not only line.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image rotates around its center. Thus for any point, first rotate the point around image center, then adjust for offset in rotated image.

To rotate around given origin:

```py
def rotate(pt, radians, origin):
    x, y = pt
    offset_x, offset_y = origin
    adjusted_x = (x - offset_x)
    adjusted_y = (y - offset_y)
    cos_rad = math.cos(radians)
    sin_rad = math.sin(radians)
    qx = offset_x + cos_rad * adjusted_x + sin_rad * adjusted_y
    qy = offset_y + -sin_rad * adjusted_x + cos_rad * adjusted_y
    return qx, qy
```

```py
h, w = original_image.shape[:2]
origin = (w/2, h/2)
x1_new, y1_new = rotate([x1, y1], np.radians(angle), origin)
x2_new, y2_new = rotate([x2, y2], np.radians(angle), origin)
```

Then calculate offset in rotated image:

```py
h_new, w_new = rotated_image.shape[:2]
xoffset, yoffset = (w_new - w)/2, (h_new - h)/2
```

and adjust points:

```py
x1_new, y1_new = x1_new+xoffset, y1_new+yoffset
x2_new, y2_new = x2_new+xoffset, y2_new+yoffset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let opencv to do the calculations for you.

```
# read image
image = cv2.imread('tony-sebastian-AhMo_n7KRbw-unsplash.jpg')
# Crop for better view
image = image[2000:6000,:,:][::5,::5,:]

# define a point to track @ x=400 and y=700
image[700:720,400:420,:] = 0

# Invert color order to view it with plt.imshow()
image = image[:,:,::-1]

plt.imshow(image)
```

[image]

```
# points to track (x, y)
point_to_track = (400, 700)

# assuming your desired rotation is 60 degrees
angle = -80

# Get the image center (assumes the point of rotation is the image center)
center = (image.shape[1] // 2, image.shape[0] // 2)

# create the rotation matrix which is required to rotate images and points (everything as a numpy array)
rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)

# rotate image
rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rotation_matrix, image.shape[:2])

plt.imshow(rotated_image)
```

[image]

```
# find new position of points after rotation
point_after_rotation = cv2.transform(np.array([[point_to_track]]), rotation_matrix)[0][0]

print(point_after_rotation)
```

[105 452]